# how can I change the Checkbox color in Material-UI's Autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm using React and `Autocomplete` provided by Material-UI. I'm not able to change the color of the Checkbox component. Here's my code:

```
<Checkbox
  icon={icon}
  checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
  style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
  value={options}
  name="isChecked"
  color='primary'
  checked={state.isChecked}
  onChange={updateHandler}
/>
```

I also tried using `className` but it didn't work. It only happens if the checkboxes are inside `Autocomplete`.

Comment: it only works for autocomplete... For the checkbox inside Autocomplete component it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using the code from [this](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#checkboxes) example. If so, the issue is that you're using custom icon component for your `Checkbox`, you need to apply the css style on the icon component that you pass in `checkedIcon` props:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    color: green[400],
    "&$checked": {
      color: green[600]
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={<CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />}
            // change to this line below to fix the issue
            checkedIcon={<CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" className={classes.root} />}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" />}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66747535/how-can-i-change-the-checkbox-color-in-autocomplete]